# Save Windows.UI.Composition.CompositionDrawingSurface to file

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

I am creating object using following code:

```
CompositionDrawingSurface uiElementBitmapSurface;
            using (var canvasBitmap = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes(
                    canvasDevice, pixels,
                    bitmap.PixelWidth,
                    bitmap.PixelHeight,
                    DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized,
                    dpi)
            )
            {
                var areaToRender = new Rect(100, 100, Control.ActualWidth, Control.ActualHeight);
                Windows.UI.Composition.CompositionDrawingSurface surface = compositionDevice.CreateDrawingSurface(
                                        new Size(areaToRender.Width, areaToRender.Height),
                                        DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized, DirectXAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

                using (var session = CanvasComposition.CreateDrawingSession(uiElementBitmapSurface))
                {
                    session.DrawImage(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, areaToRender);
                }
            }
```

Please help to convert uiElementBitmapSurface object to file.

Comment: Could you please tell  what file format you want to save to?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT want to save it to .png or .jpg

Answer (score 1):

Call this:

https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBitmap_SaveAsync.htm

I have not tried this myself by the way, I just googled the documentation. But it sure looks like what you are looking for.

Comment: given link helps in saving canvasbitmap to file but my requirement is to save conpositionDrawingSurface to file